# Trouble using ArrayFormula and Desref in google sheet

Tags: arrays, offset

I have a column data with similar information:

- Noise [R11]
- Radiation [R12]
- Noise [R15]
- Trapped by [R09]
- Trapped by [R16]

I need to put dynamic Array where can show how many times each category (noise, radiation, ..) is repeated (the codes closed in brackets must be excluded), the configuration (results) must be like that (i only have 5x2 cells):

|  | Category | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | Noise | 2 |
| Row2 | Trapped by | 2 |
| Row3 | ..other | .. |
| Row4 | ..other | .. |
| Row5 | Next 4: | n |

n is the number [1,2,3..] where the user can write to show the next four categories (others) in the row 1 to row 4. For this reason I only need one formula (dynamic array) combined with other functions.

in the first column I put the formula
=DESREF(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(IZQUIERDA(M17:M,LENB(M17:M)-6))),n,0,4,1)

But it doesn't work. (a friend commented Desref function only works in range but not in array). However, I need to use other alternative to redefine the array with only one formula because i only have (5x2) free cells.
Someboby can help me?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with query

```
=query(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(if(M17:M="",,LEFT(M17:M,LENB(M17:M)-6)))),"limit 5")
```

Comment: It works, but how can redefine the resulting array (nx1)? Desref function has the option to specify the row and length where the array will be cutted. Thanks by the first answer

Comment: The reason is that desref (offset) applies to a range, not an array. So you can first put your formula `unique` in a cell, then apply `desref` on the **range** where your formula gives the answer but you can't combine the two formula in one.

Comment: is there other alternative to make this operation. I don't have more free cells in the sheet . for this reason i need to use one formula. I will explain more:

Comment: I think query is one of the easiest ways as posted here ...

Comment: mike, i've updated the main post.